# Meaning of 'private' keyword in Alloy? Meaning of 'enum' declaration?

Tags: alloy

The [Alloy 4 grammar](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy4-grammar.txt) allows signature declarations (and some other things) to carry a `private` keyword.  It also allows Allow specifications to contain enumeration declarations of the form

```
enum nephews { hughie, louis, dewey }
enum ducks { donald, daisy, scrooge, nephews }
```

[The language reference](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf) doesn't (as far as I can tell) describe the meaning of either the `private` keyword or the `enum` construct.

Is there documentation available?  Or are they in the grammar as constructs that are reserved for future specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my unofficial understanding of those two keywords.

```
enum nephews { hughie, louis, dewey }
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
open util/ordering[nephews] as nephewsOrd

abstract sig nephews {}

one sig hughie extends nephews {}
one sig louis extends nephews {}
one sig dewey extends nephews {}

fact {
  nephewsOrd/first = hughie
  nephewsOrd/next = hughie -> louis + louis -> dewey
}
```

The `private` keyword means that if a sig has the `private` attribute, its label is private within the same module.  The same applies for private fields and private functions.

Comment: Thank you; this is helpful.  I suppose it follows that using the same name both in an enumeration and as the name of another enumeration would be an error.  (Well, that's easily checkable, why am I asking when I can find out for myself? -- yes, Alloy 4.2RC flags it as an error.  OK, thanks again.)

Comment: I see also that `private` is documented at http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/quickguide/private.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous accepted answer, I'd like to add some useful insights coming from a one-week experience with Alloy on `enum`s, in particular on the main differences with standard `sig`.

If you use `abstract sig + extend`, you'll come up with a model in which there are many sets corresponding to the same concept. Maybe an example could clarify it better.
Suppose somthing like

```
sig Car {
    dameges: set Damage
}
```

You have the choice to use

```
abstract sig Damage {}
sig MajorDamage, MinorDamage extends Damage {}
```

vs

```
enum Damage {
    MajorDamage, MinorDamage
}
```

In the first case we can come up wiht a model with different MinorDamage atoms (MinorDamage0, MinorDamage1, ...) associatet to Cars, while in the second case you always have only one MinorDamage to which different Cars can refer.

It could have some sense in this case to use an `abstract sig + extend` form (because you can decide to track different MinorDamage or MajorDamage elements).

On the other hand, if you want to have a `currentState: set State`, it could be better to use an

```
enum State {Damaged, Parked, Driven}
```

to map the concept, in order to have exactly three `State` to which each `Car` can refer to. In this way, in the `Visualizer`, you can decide to project your model on exactly one of the states and it will highlight all the `Car`s associated to this state. You can't do that with the `abstract + extend` construct, of course, because projecting over `MajorDamage0` will highlight only the `Car` associated to that `Damage` and nothing else.

So, in conclusion, it really depends on what you have to do.

Also, keep in mind that if you have an enum composed by X elements and execute

```
run some_predicate for Y
```

where Y < X, Alloy produces no instance at all. 
So, in our last example, we can't have a Y < 3.

As a last note, enums don't always appear in the Visualizer if you use the Magic Layout button, but as I said previously you can "project" your model over the enum and switch between the different elements of the enum.